# Getting -inf values when calculating zonal statistics from raster layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, zonal-statistics

I am trying to get some summary statistics from a raster layer (CRS EPSG:3035 - ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe - Projected) of forest biomass for each polygon in a shapefile layer. I have used the zonal statistics tool in QGIS before without a problem. However, for this particular raster layer, the output has only -inf values for statistics such as sum, median, mean.

I think the problem might be related to the no data values, because in the information for the raster layer these values are specified as -inf.

[image: information from raster layer]

I have tried to change the no data values following several previous posts, but either it doesn't work, or the other values in the layer are also changed.

I have tried several different options and still can't get the values for the polygons.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the CRS/spatial reference for both datasets.